# Get string between first separator and last dot

Tags: php, split, preg-replace, extension-methods, separator

Sorry for this, I am a very old developer. After have been stopped developing 6 year ago due to a serious cerebral infarction my head is not so fresh anymore, I forgot many thing and also, as you can see, a simple one as this one.

I want to make some update to an old script I have made 10 years ago, which I use to order and manage my e-books collection.

Having had some new e-books from a friend I need now to extract the author's name from the files:

```php
$file_name = Bitcoin en andere cryptovaluta - Mary-Jane Lasterie-Janssen.epub
$file_name = Fur - Grazia Hattem-Le Clercq.epub
$file_name = Sprookjes van Planeet Ur - Grazia Hattem-Le Clercq.epub
Het jasje van Luis Martin - Gilles van der Loo.epub
La divina commedia - Dante Alighieri.epub
```

I need to get the full author's name which is between de first separator and the dot before the extension.

I have tried to use preg_replace() for this and it works for situations like this one, where only ONE separator is present in the string:

```php
$author_name = preg_replace('/(.*)-(.*)\.epub/', '$2', $file_name);
Het jasje van Luis Martin - Gilles van der Loo.epub
La divina commedia - Dante Alighieri.epub
```

But not when multiple separator are in the string.

After I have got the author's name I will like to have the .epub without the name so I will end up with this result:

Original .epub file:

```php
$file_name = Bitcoin en andere cryptovaluta - Mary-Jane Lasterie-Janssen.epub
```

What I need:

```php
$author_name = Mary-Jane Lasterie-Janssen
$file_name   = Bitcoin en andere cryptovaluta.epub
```

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: do you want like this: https://3v4l.org/Q3p97

Comment: I think the place to look at is the " - " (space hypen space), which is different from hypen(s) which may exist in other places of the string.

Comment: @KenLee  may or may not be. That needs to be clarify by OP. that's why didn't posted as an answer. I am not good at regex and that's why trying to get other way around

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```php
$filename = 'Bitcoin en andere cryptovaluta - Mary-Jane Lasterie-Janssen.epub';
$author = "";
$filename = preg_replace_callback('~(.*) - (.*)\.epub~', function ($m) use (&$author) 
 { $author = $m[2]; return $m[1] . ".epub"; }, $filename);
echo "Author = $author\nFilename = $filename"; 
// => Author = Mary-Jane Lasterie-Janssen
//    Filename = Bitcoin en andere cryptovaluta.epub
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/AWe5h).

The regex matches like this:

- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (so, all from the start till last occurrence of the subsequent patterns)
- `-`  - space, hyphen, space
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\.epub` - `.epub` string.

The `preg_replace_callback` function is used to "simultaneously" replace with regex and extract a part of a regex match. `$author` is passed to the anonymous function used as the replacement argument with the `&` prefix so that it could be written (re-assigned) a value to.

Comment: Hi Wiktor thank you very much for this snippet. This is just what I am needing to go on.Regards Franco. (just up-voted)

Comment: @Franco Exception : https://3v4l.org/UOJeB. you gave string with multiple file and authors name

Comment: Hallo @Wiktor, the .epub file I need to split is the real e-book and not just a string or representation of it. I need the returned $filename.epub still to be te real book. Splitting in the way you propose makes the book still readable? Do not became just a string with an extension? Thank you for your answer